# Getting most recent date from multiple multiple columns pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas `DataFrame`. I would like to get the most recent date ('2022-01-06' in this case) from column `dt1` and `dt2`. Is `df[["dt1", "dt2"]].max()` correct in this case?

| a | dt1 | dt2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-04 |
| 2 | 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-05 |
| 3 | 2022-01-03 | 2022-01-06 |

Comment: are you looking for: `df[["dt1", "dt2"]].max().max()`?

Comment: I was about to comment that `df[["dt1", "dt2"]].stack().max()` could be faster but nope, `max().max()` seems to be the fastest.

Comment: `.max().max()` solved it. Thanks!